# Which day of the week does the App Store get the most traffic?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Pretty self explanatory...Which day of the week does the App Store get the most traffic?

I run into this dilemma every time I release an app. Anybody have raw statistics and not just anecdotes?

**Edit** I'm referring to actual App Store visitor traffic. I'm trying to maximize views as a new release. Don't have a lot of marketing budget so those early days count.

Comment: The App Store always gets the most traffic tomorrow.

Comment: Closed. ha. I quit StackOverflow. Programming and business are becoming more and more intertwined.  This is a very relevant question. Sorry it doesn't fit into the box.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why this is really much of a dilemma that you run into every time you release an app.
I really don't feel this is the kind of thing you should be worried about if your goal is to actually increase the appeal of your app. There are so many more important and more consistent variables, especially compared to the small handful of potential browsers that this kind of "optimization" might bring you.

**Here are some more important things to concern yourself with:**

1. The quality of your app.
2. See number one.

...oh yeah, and also see [The Guide to App Store Marketing](http://spreadsong.com/the_guide_to_app_store_marketing) for more pro tips.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree. A lot of really bad apps get into the top 100 because of really good marketing. A lot of really great apps never get close. "If you build it, they will come" does not apply to apps.

Comment: @retailevolved: You're right that there are exceptions to the rule. In general developers have pretty good luck with this, though. What usually gets in the way of such a perfect principle is stupid users who'd rather buy a flashlight or a farting app, regardless of the excellent quality of other more useful apps. But even the argument you made concerning good marketing doesn't seem to extend to posting the app to the store on the perfect day.

Comment: Unfortunately, "stupid users" can control the fate of an app :) I get really irked when I see a gag app - like the one that pretends to find a phone based on the phone number - in the top 100. Your point is taken and I agree that quality is extremely important. It's unfortunate, but release day has become a crux of marketing for iPhone dev hobbyists such as myself. It's not truly marketing, but it is immediate exposure that gives the app a chance to stick.

Comment: @retailevolved So by your own logic - it's pointless trying to gauge the best day for a release because you stated yourself that stupid users will always choose a fart app over anything else. Stupid users outnumber other users. As Cody said, you're **so** much better off making sure your app is as good as it can be than worrying which day to release on. It doesn't matter when you release. If your app is good at what it does, the people who want it will find it and buy it.

Comment: You're reading way too deep into my argument. Fact is that the more time you spend on the new releases page of your category, the more money you will make. More visibility = more money. It's all about getting the most number of downloads in the shortest amount of time so that the app sticks in the top 25 of your category. Everybody here is acting like I said quality doesn't count. It DOES. It's just not the only factor of success, not by a longshot.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apple have the real numbers. Developers might be able to tell you which days they get the most *sales* on, but this isn't quite the same as where the traffic comes from.

Anecdotally, it seems that the days you get most of your sales depends on the type of app. Games do better on weekends and holidays. My apps (social networking) are pretty consistent across the whole week.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal best day of the week for apps. The target audience for one type of app will have a different schedule with respect to people interested into different kind of apps.

For a particular app analyze the audience and their typical behavior and work out the best schedule for that given app. Expect to redo the work if you bring out a different app.

You are actually better off by monitoring the daily and weekly download/sales figures and use that numbers as a basis for timing an update. Users like updates to their apps and unless you have available an industrial size advertising budget then word of mouth tends to be the best bet.